# Why is my global variable getting overridden on JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript

```
var name = "Window Object";

var a = {
  name: 'manish',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

b = (a.getName = a.getName)();

console.log(b, window);
```

Above is the code that I had written on JSFiddle.

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/shettyrahul8june/o49jn5fm/

**Variable b** returns **result** instead of **Window Object**. I saw that in the Window object there is a property called **name** which has result stored as string. But I am not sure why my global variable a didn't override that variable. Thanks in anticipation.

**Edit:** Guys I think I wasn't clear with my question. I know it's referencing the window object's name from JSFiddle. But I have also written **var name = "Window Object"**.

Why my variable name didn't over ride Window objects name because I think even var name that I have declared should have got attached to window object. Is it because, the fiddle has a wrapper object where name gets assigned like

**JSFiddleWrapper = {
  name: "Window Object"
}**

and hence it's referencing window.name?

Comment: You are calling `a.getName` without its context, so it is defaulting to `window`, an in JSFiddle `window.name` is `result`. Your code is redundant, just do `b = a.getName()`, surely?

Comment: Compare [the same code in Strict Mode](https://jsfiddle.net/o49jn5fm/1/)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I know it's redundant. I am testing how "this" behaves when we write (a.getName = a.getName)(); ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is something interesting whe you are doing `a.getName = a.getName`. The `a.getName` function is reassigned to the same . The parenthesis just returns that function with the `Window` as its context. So when inside the function you do `this`, it refers to the Window object.

```js
var name = "Window Object";

var a = {
  name: 'manish',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

b = (a.getName = a.getName)();

console.log(b);
```

You can use `bind` to change the context. Check the following snippet:

```js
var name = "Window Object";

var a = {
  name: 'manish',
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

b = (a.getName = a.getName).bind(a)();

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) behaves very different from most other languages. Its precise behavior depends entirely on how the function is called, notice:

```
console.log(a.getName(), window); // manish Window
```

This correctly gets `name` from `a`, because `this` is inferred to refer to the object on the left of the period. But here:

```
f = a.getName;
console.log(f(), window); // result Window
```

The function, `f`, is in a sense 'unbound' from the object at the time it's called, and so `this` is inferred to refer to the Window itself (in JSFiddle the `name` of the window in the result panel is `'result'`).

One fairly easy way to solve this is to use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
b = (a.getName = a.getName.bind(a))();
console.log(b, window); // manish Window
```

Comment: wow almost same answer at the same instant... :) yea `bind`, `call` or `apply` can be used to change the context.

Comment: @Ayan yup. Very similar descriptions of the problem and proposed solutions. (+1)